# woocommerce 4 category items on a row

Tags: woocommerce, row, categories, items

I am looking for a way to change the number of categories per row in woocommerce. I found a lot of options to change the number of products per row. But I use pages with only categories and want to change the number of each row there.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show us what you tried already!

Comment: Sorry, this is not resolved.